# Struggling to update to latest openssl version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, fips

I've downloaded openssl-fips-2.0.14.tar.gz from the official website on my Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine and executed the following commands:

```
tar -xvf openssl-fips-2.0.14.tar.gz
cd openssl-fips-2.0.14
./config 
make 
make install
```

Afterwards I type openssl version but it is still returning the older version. I know that it's looking in /usr/bin and there's a binary file belonging to the older openssl version in that directory. I'm trying to find the binary of the newest openssl version (2.0.14) but just can't find it. I want to make sure that when I type openssl version it will return the latest and not the older version. Can someone please help.

Comment: `openssl-fips-2.0.14.tar.gz` is just the FIPS Object Module. You still need to install the FIPS Capable library. The FIPS Capable library is the one with the `openssl` program and `libcrypto` and `libssl` libraries. And you will still need to create soft links or modify your path.

Answer (score 2):

The file *openssl-fips-2.0.14.tar.gz* is the source for the FIPS Object Module and not OpenSSL itself. Read through the OpenSSL FIPS User Guide at https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf, especially the section on creating the FIPS module and building a FIPS capable OpenSSL.

That said, any binaries will be underneath the /usr/local/ssl directory tree by default and your PATH environment variable will need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify --prefix to the configure script, it will install in /usr/local/ssl by default (see INSTALLTOP variable from Makefile.fips in your source files). If you want both versions to coexist on your system, you'll have to either call the full path each time, or:
- add an alias in your .bashrc:

```
alias newopenssl="/path/to/new/openssl_binary"
```

then source .bashrc, or:

- edit your PATH var in .bashrc and add the path to the new ssl installation before the rest of your PATHs, i.e.:

```
export PATH="/path/to/new/openssl_dir:$PATH"
```

then source .bashrc.

If you want to change the install path, I recommend reading [this article](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#PREFIX_and_OPENSSLDIR).